# How to make Stored Procedure variable where the value doesn't need to be pass from the controller?

Tags: variables, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, razor

I Need to Perform the following:But it shows the error that  **"stored procedure expects paramater @c "**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[clearcart]
@uid bigint,
@mid bigint,
@count bigint,
@c as bigint output
as
BEGIN
        delete from [dbo].[cart] where [dbo].[cart].uid=@uid ;

set @c=(select mcount from [dbo].[material] where mid=@mid);

if(@c!=0)
begin
          update [dbo].[material] set mcount=(mcount-@count) where mid=@mid;
end
else
begin
           update [dbo].[material] set mcount=0 where mid=@mid;
end
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops,Made a Big mistake,The Answer Here,ie,we dont have to create variable like that ,can create locally inside begin

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[clearcart]
@uid bigint,
@mid bigint,
@count bigint

as
BEGIN
declare @c as bigint;
        delete from [dbo].[cart] where [dbo].[cart].uid=@uid ;

set @c=(select mcount from [dbo].[material] where mid=@mid);

if(@c!=0)
begin
          update [dbo].[material] set mcount=(mcount-@count) where mid=@mid;
end
else
begin
           update [dbo].[material] set mcount=0 where mid=@mid;
end
END
```